# Fetching manually set Timezone on Windows machine

Tags: java, java-8

I want to be able to fetch whatever timezone my machine is set to without specifying the timezone manually in code. I may not be locationally not in that time zone but the goal is to use the timezone the computer is set to.

Locationally my Timezone region is America/New_York using ZoneId.systemDefault() (EDT). However, I have set my computer's timezone to Pacific Time (PDT). I have tried the below-specified code. What is the best way to achieve this in Java 8?

```
LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), hour, minute, 0);
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = currentDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        date = Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
```

I expect the time zone to be Amrica/Dawson or America/Tijuana (UTC -08:00) but instead I get America/New_York (UTC -05:00)

Comment: I'm more interested in how you're getting `-05:00[America/New_York]` when it's currently daylight savings time (I get `-04:00[America/New_York]`).

Comment: `Calendar.getInstance().getTimezone()`?

Comment: Using timedatectl on Centos 7, changing the system timezone gets me the expected result, so I'm guessing that how you are trying to change your system's timezone is not doing what you think it is

Comment: @markspace Already tried that. Thanks though.

Comment: @Matt hi. In what way did you change your timezone? I have mine changed using Windows settings' Date and Time > Change the time zone.

Comment: @CatherineAustria I don't have a windows computer, so I cannot test this on windows unfortunately, but what I do know is that your code works on centos when I change the system's timezone

Comment: @Matt ah. Thanks for your efforts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full code that I made to get my answer:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(null);
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "");
//(above) force fetches and sets the JVM to the timezone the system is set to
LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), hour, minute, 0);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = currentDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
date = Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
```

The problem was that I may have changed my system time zone as mentioned by @Matt. However, I found that the JVM time was not changed despite the manual timezone change.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(null);
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "");
```

(above) Allowed me to clear the previously set JVM timezone.

**EDIT 04/26/2019**

I updated my logic to support day light savings for Pacific Time. I ran into an issue where my time was setting PST instead of PDT, so instead of the above logic, I changed it to grab the zone ID and use that with the Calendar class. Below is the completed logic:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(null);
System.clearProperty​("user.timezone"); //04/26/2019 EDIT This was suggested as a cleaner way of clearing the user timezone in the system.
//(above) force fetches and sets the JVM to the timezone the system is set to
System.out.println("Zone: "+ZoneId.systemDefault()+" isDaylightsavings? "+ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().isDaylightSavings(Instant.now())+" currentDateTime: "+currentDateTime);
String timeZone = ""+ZoneId.systemDefault();
Calendar selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone)); // important when it comes to determining PDT or PST
date = selectedDate.getTime();
```

Comment: I think, `System.clearProperty​("user.timezone");` would be cleaner than `System.setProperty("user.timezone", "");`…

Comment: @Holger Could you explain the advantages?

Comment: It documents the intention: you want to clear the property (remove the explicit setting) rather than setting it to an empty string. Not having a mapping might also save a bit memory, compared to holding a mapping to an empty string, but that's negligible.

Comment: @Holger Thanks! A good thing to note for everyone reading this.